# How to send custom error report from application to Hockey

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, hockeyapp

How can i send custom error report from Xamarin forms application to Hockey?
I am able to get crash reports through hockey sdk integration. I want to handle exceptions and send custom messages
to hockey.

I tried sending reports by this way.

```
HockeyApp.BITHockeyManager.SharedHockeyManager?.MetricsManager?.TrackEvent("custom error report");
```

I enabled hockey in app delegate in this way

```
var hocMgr = BITHockeyManager.SharedHockeyManager;
hocMgr.Configure("appKey");
hocMgr.DisableUpdateManager = true;
hocMgr.StartManager();
hocMgr.Authenticator.AuthenticateInstallation();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just yet (see this [recent link](https://support.hockeyapp.net/discussions/problems/55184-what-are-the-reaons-why-the-ios-sdk-doesnt-support-sending-handled-exceptions) from support). HockeyApp is primarily designed for 'hard crashes' and not for event tracking or custom Exception handling. Besides the beta distribution and feedback of course.

With the merge of Xamarin Insights this will come, but it will take some time!

Custom event tracking is [in the preseason already](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/general-account-management-2/getting-started-with-custom-events-preseason). But you'll have to be accepted in the program first.

Comment: Can we use hockey crash reporting to apps submitted to app store?

Comment: Apps which are already in the app store? Or apps you are going to submit to the app store? Your app does have to use the HockeyApp SDK. But it is designed to work with apps that are in the app store that is the whole purpose :)

Comment: Thanks. I ve integrated HockeySDK. At present app is still under development and is shared with testers using hockey itself. Wanted to make sure i will get crash reports even after submitting to app store.

Comment: That is the whole purpose so yes it will be!